# Return portion of object from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service that returns an HoursReport object:

```
    public class HoursReport
    {
        public List<Client> MyClients { get; set; }
        public String Start {get; set;}
        public String End {get; set;}
        public String Key {get; set;}
        public String DontIncludeMe {get; set;}
    }
```

Here is the interface I set up:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Punches/{clientId}?start={start}&end={end}&raw={raw}")]
    [Description("Retrieve hours information for each client.")]
    HoursReport Punches(string start, string end, string clientId, string raw);
```

My question is: can I return only a portion of my HoursReport object?  Can I decide which portion dynamically?

Comment: how about returning null values for the `HoursReport` properties based on condition?

Answer (score 0):

Short answr :

No you can not

Long answer you can, if you override return function of API

If you use NewtoinJson :

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
response.ClearContent();
response.ContentType = "application/json";
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream))
{
    using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
   {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new { Start = “lol”, Key=”myKey”, MyClients = myList });
   }
}
```

Edit : I use this function to change my Json returns :

```
public static class ServicesHelper
    {
        public static void SendJson(HttpResponse response, object data)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            //serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream))
            {
                using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
                }
            }
        }

        public static string ToJson(object data)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  The best way to accomplish this is to treat all your 3rd party dependency objects as something that shouldn't be consumed directly by your API's clients.  When you create a new object that represents the JSON structure you intend to return, you can decorate it to only serialize those properties.

To move data between the 3rd party dependent objects and your API objects, look at something like a Mapper pattern.  It takes in the 3rd party dependent object and transforms it into your new object.

example:

```
public class HoursReport
{
    public List<Client> MyClients { get; set; }
    public String Start {get; set;}
    public String End {get; set;}
    public String Key {get; set;}
    public String DontIncludeMe {get; set;}
}

public class HoursReportResponse
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName="start")]
   public string Start {get; set;}
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName="end")]
   public string End {get; set;}
}

public class HoursReportMapper
{
    public HoursReportResponse Map(HoursReport hoursReport)
    {
        return new HoursReportResponse
        {
            Start = hoursReport.Start,
            End = hoursReport.End
        };
    }
}
```